# Running background jobs in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How is the best way to run a background job to convert video formats in Rails 3.  I am using FFmpeg.  I would like for the script to execute immediately after the video model is saved.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delayed_job is one of the more popular methods. I would recommend it.

Video:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Delayed_Job, I got it up and running last night and it's working very well!

Answer (score 2):

[Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) is another popular alternative to [Delayed_Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). Both are well trusted so it could just come down to your own personal preference.

Note that as far as I know, the delayed_job I've linked to on Github is the more standard version used now even though it is a fork of the original. That was something that confused me when I first looked at it.

Answer (score 2):

[Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) (based on Celluloid and Redis) is well worth taking a look at as well.